# Edit Result LINQ to Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, razor

I have a table called "Costumers" and other table called "Adress", so this is what I want to do:

I want do "select" on Consumers and Address and fill a DropDownList with the fields Costumers.Name and Adress.Street. The dropdownlist will be like this:

Jack Jhonsom - Montain View (CA)
Robert Balmer - Washington (DC)
Mariah Bendley - Morgantown(WV)

How I do it?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 RAZOR,  Entity Framework

Comment: I have just this code: 
var query = from c in ctx.Costumers select c.Name;

Comment: query contains list of names you want to show in the drop list, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be one of those solutions will help:

```
List<SelectListItem> result;

//**If you have relation Customer.Address
var customers = db.Customers.ToList();

var items = (from n in customers 
             select new SelectListItem
             {
               text = String.Format("{0}-{1}", n.Name, n.Address.City),
               value = n.customerID.ToString();
             }).ToList();
result.AddRange(items);

return result;

//If you don't have relation Customer.Address
var customers = db.Customers.ToList();
var addresses = db.Addresses.ToList();
var items = (from n in customers
             join b in addresses on b.addressid equals n.addressid
             select new SelectListItem
             {
               text = String.Format("{0}-{1}", n.Name, b.City),
               value = n.customerID.ToString();
             }).ToList();
result.AddRange(items);

return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

```
var items = user.Select(u => string.Format("{0} - {1}", u.Name, u.Address.Street))
```

Comment: Tanks Aviran, but my problem is not "how I will show it" but How I will build a query using LINQ to Entities that unify 2 fields (Costumers.Name and Adress.Street). Like the example that I built:
 NAME + "-" + ADRESS

Comment: please provide your class structure so I can help